ApplicationIntent = ReadOnly and Writes queries
I'm confused about behavior of connection string that specifies ApplicationIntent = ReadOnly and write queries in SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition.
Let's say, Availability Group has a primary - X1 and two replicas - X2 and X3 and let's say I want to balance reads and writes, so that all the writes would go to primary and reads to two replicas.
If application that connects to SQL and does both read and write queries using a single connection string that has ApplicationIntent = ReadOnly, does it mean that it will error out if application will try to run write query or it will simply redirect this query to the primary ?


If application that connects to SQL and does both read and write queries using a single connection string that has ApplicationIntent = ReadOnly, does it mean that it will error out if application will try to run write query

Yes.  If you have read-only routing configured then the read-intent connections will be redirected to a read-only replica.  They will remain connected to the read-only replica for the duration of the connection.  Routing happens only when initially connecting to the AG.  So if routing redirects the client to a read replica, any write query will fail.

Thank you for the reply. So in essence, it means that application needs to have two connection strings: one for the writes and one for the reads...

Yep.  And sometimes you need to read from the Read/Write connection, as the Read-Only replicas have some lag.  For instance when a user modifies data and the application immediately queries the data that was modified, the read needs to come from the primary replica if you need to see the modified data.
